# Why can't I center this simple div?

Tags: html, css

sorry for bothering you guys... but i've been trying for too long now to center a simple div. I tried so many things and I couldn't find what's wrong but would like to understand why since i'm a still a newbie.

So to make it short I would like to center the blue and white arrow horizontaly.

This is my site: [xaviergodbout.com](http://xaviergodbout.com/)

Thanks to anyone who'd help me!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the section named ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add `text-align:center` to div and it will center.

```
#down {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 85vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I'm feeling like an idiot right now... A huge thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways to centre a `div` element.

First method, involves setting the `div` to `display: inline-block;` and settings the enveloping `div` to `text-align: centre;`.

**CSS:**

```
.my-div-container {
    text-align: center;
}

.my-div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="my-div-container">
    <div class="my-div">My div</div>
</div>
```

Second method, involves centre aligning the `div` via the `position` and `transform` attributes. Here's how:

**CSS:**

```
.my-div {
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 1024px;
}
```

Third method, fix sizing the `div` and using `margin` to centre it.

**CSS:**

```
.my-div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.waves-effect{
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.classname{
width:100%;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to centre a block horizontally is to use `margin: auto`. It also requires changing the `display` block from the default `inline`:

```
div#down>a {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

By the way, be careful with centring elements. Once you centre the arrow, the text looks off-centre because it’s left-aligned.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The will be centered aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
#down {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```